# CipherOutputStream and ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, cryptography, zip

I am trying to create zip file which contains encrypted file and encrypted key for this file. Here is my code:

zip

```
 ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("zip.zip"));
```

connected streams

```
 PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
 PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
```

getting secret key

```
 KeyGenerator keygen=KeyGenerator.getInstance(storageSettings.getFileEncryptAlgorithm());
 SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();
```

getting cipher

```
 Сipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

now I make cipher output to pipedOutputStream

```
 CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(pos,cipher);
 byte[] m = new byte[1024];
 int position;
 while ((position = someInputData.read(m, 0, 1024)) >= 0)
 {
  cos.write(m, 0, position);
 }
```

adding to zip and its there but next file would be empty

```
 addFileToZip(zout, pis, backup.getFilename());
 cos.flush();
```

Now I want to encrypt SecretKey key via rsa and I have keypair from file

```
 String publicKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(storageSettings.getPublicKeyFile()).toURI())));
 publicKeyContent = publicKeyContent.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
 KeyFactory keyfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(storageSettings.getKeyEnryptAlgorithm());
 X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyContent));
 RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyfactory.generatePublic(keySpecX509);
 cipher = Cipher.getInstance(storageSettings.getKeyEnryptAlgorithm());
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

Now I wanna create second file with encrypted key but I have empty file in zip, and all files would be empty except first

```
 CipherOutputStream cos1 = new CipherOutputStream(pos,cipher);
 byte[] tmp = key.getEncoded();
 cos1.write(tmp);
 addFileToZip(zout, pis,"key.txt");
```

Here is addFileToZip()

```
public void addFileToZip(ZipOutputStream zout,InputStream data,String filename) throws IOException
{
    zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));
    byte[] m = new byte[data.available()];
    data.read(m);
    zout.write(m);
    zout.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: Could you log how many bytes are read / written in your `addFileToZip` method?  I woudn't rely on the `data.available()` method for files (mainy bigger files). Regardless they are other issues (like using DESEde in ECB mode)